# Unable to access images from drawable folder android studio

Tags: android-studio, android-drawable

I get following error when i try to access a image placed in drawable folder ( a png file) from either .java file or from .Xml file.
Error: cannot find symbol variable "image name"
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

I added  below piece of code to build.gradle..

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile)
{
    options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:deprecation"
}
```

Now after compilation i get only error Error: cannot find symbol variable "image name".

not sure what is the exact issue.

R.drawable.imagename or @drawable/imagename is the way i am trying to access the images